# htaccess rewrite rule with manual Query String

Tags: php, .htaccess

I write the rule as

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_&]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_&]+)_in_([a-zA-Z0-9_&]+)-([0-9_&]+).php$ test.php?city=$3&subcat=$2&cat=$1&pageNo=$4
```

In my file the url passes as test-2.php It works fine.

I want to pass this as `test-2.php?querystring5=somevalue`

i.e I need the above 4 query string (`city=$3&subcat=$2&cat=$1&pageNo=$4`) and manually pass the 5th query string.

please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but apache can append the original querystring to it if you add the flag QSA. Just put ' [QSA]' after the rule to apply this flag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to append the original query to your rewritten query. To do so you can use the {QUERY_STRING} variable.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_&]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_&]+)_in_([a-zA-Z0-9_&]+)-([0-9_&]+).php$ test.php?city=$3&subcat=$2&cat=$1&pageNo=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

You may also use the [QSA] flag as Gerben commented, although I've always used {QUERY_STRING}.